# Middleman / Ruby : accents not shown property

Tags: html, ruby, middleman

I'm using middleman. When i run the server I get this:

`LA NOUVELLE FAÇON - Développez votre patrimoine.`

When I do `middleman build`, I get this in the HTML:

`LA NOUVELLE FAÃ‡ON - DÃ©veloppez votre patrimoine.`

I added: `set :encoding, "utf-8"`

But it does not work. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem addressed to markdown processors behind middleman. This gem is provided to deal with: https://github.com/msadouni/middleman-utf8-partial

And don’t forget to put:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in the very top of your main template’s `<head>` section.